# Trapezoid rule when width is not 1 program doesn't finish (C)

Tags: c, for-loop, increment

The way width is found by (upper bound - lower bound) / n(# of trapezoids desired) and in my code it works when the width is one however if its something other than one the program will not finish itself, I suspect the problem is how i am incrementing it in the for loop of "func"

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double func(double x) {
return x * x;
}

double trap(double lower, double upper, int n) {
double width,area = 0;

width = (upper - lower) / n;
//printf("%lf\n",width);

int i;
for (i = lower; i < upper; i += width) {
    area += (func(i) + ((func(i + width)))) / 2 * width;
    //printf("%lf\n",area);
}
return area;
}

int main(void) {

double lower,upper,x;
int n;


while (1) {

    printf("lower limit: ");
    scanf("%lf",&lower);
    printf("upper limit (should be greater than %.2lf): ",lower);
    scanf("%lf",&upper);

    if (upper <= lower) {
        printf("[ERROR] the lower limit must be less"); 
        printf("than the upper limit: please try again\n");
        continue;   
    }

    printf("number of trapezoids: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); 

    if (n <= 0) {
        printf("[ERROR] the number of trapezoids must be");
        printf("greater than 0; please try again\n");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

printf("%lf\n", trap(lower,upper,n));



return 0;
```

Comment: i just tried that and it didnt resolve the issue

Comment: `int i;` --> `double i;`

Comment: @John Foster You definately want to avoid mixing ints and doubles in your loop increment/decrement.  If width is less than 1, i will never change - could easily be your issue.  Try with width > 1

Comment: that mightve solved my problem thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the [analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441798/15168) by [Tibrogargan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487517/tibrogargan), but not with the suggested remedy.  Repeatedly adding floating point values can lead to problems with accumulated error in the loop control.  The loop control should count with integers, and you use the counter to calculate the value of the x-coordinate on each iteration.

I think you should use a loop similar to:

```
double old_v = func(lower);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    double x = lower + ((upper - lower) * i) / n;
    double v = func(x);
    area += width * (old_v + v) / 2.0;
    old_v = v;
}
```

This calls the function about half as often for good measure.  You can probably improve things still further by noting that the first and last values are used once each, and all the intermediate values are used twice, and multiplying by `width` and dividing by `2.0` on each iteration is superfluous, therefore.  You could use:

```
double x_sum = func(lower) + func(upper);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    x_sum += 2.0 * func(lower + ((upper - lower) * i) / n);
double area = x_sum * width / 2.0;
```

And there are probably other techniques that could, maybe even should, be used to improve the stability of the sum.  You could move the `(upper - lower)` calculation out of the loop, but the chances are high that the compiler will do that anyway.

<sup>*Warning: untested code!*</sup>

Note that you should have debugged your code either with a debugger or by adding print statements to the `trap()` function that identified the values in use.  When you saw the same value for `i` over and over again, you'd have realized there was a problem with the increment.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the loop increment.  When converting width from double to int, the fractional part of the double is discarded.  This causes any value of width between (non-inclusive) -1.0 and 1.0 to be converted to 0.